Intune - MacOS - Language Setup Screen
Recently I realized that there seems to be no option in Intune to let the user choose the “language settings” during the initial setup.
When you buy a MacBook, you get the option to choose which language you want to use right at the beginning. This option is not displayed for a managed device with user affiliation.
Is there a way to display it after all? I don't want users to be restricted to just one language, especially as it's not English but German.
I hope someone can help me.
Thanks you in advance.
EDIT:
As requested, I am an IT-Administrator and have full access to the whole MacOS enrollment flow.
I already tried to change every setting in the ADE-Profile one by one but did not had any kind of "language" settings to be shown in the setup.
The only time I could change the language was on the "activation" screen after wiping the device in the top left hand corner under "settings". That is not userfriendly for a normal user and not what I was aiming for.
Hope that helps a bit more.

I am confused. Is your question about intune or macOS as they seem fairly isolated from one another.

I'll try to explain it in more detail:
When you buy a new MacBook, you are asked at the beginning to select which language you speak.
There are also a few other things like FileVault, ApplePay, TouchID, etc...
However, when the device is rolled out via Intune, this language selection no longer appears.
In Intune, the enrollment profile can be used to set which options are displayed in the initial setup. For example, options such as ApplePay, TouchID or FileVault are not shown at all.
However, there is no option to show or hide the language selection.

Are you the Intune admin, or are you just using Intune devices adminned by someone else? The Intune Admin gets to decide what options are pre-set and which are presented to the user during initial setup.

Here's a list of what Apple allows MDMs to control on MacOS devices. I did not find anything related to Language here: https://support.apple.com/guide/deployment/restrictions-for-mac-depba790e53/1/web/1.0 I don't know that this answers your question, but you've still left us with a lot of questions. Have YOU reviewed the device enrollment flow and the relevant settings in your Intune portal? Please EDIT your question and share what you have tried, your role in this process, and any other information that may help us better understand your situation and needs.

@music2myear thank you for advice, edited my request.
Also I checked these deployment guide and were unable to find these settings.
The one thing I dont understand is, on iOS you'll still get the language prompt after the device is joined throught intune and wiped.
